# how to get current crypto currency price from Binance Market

Tags: node.js

how to get the current cryptocurrency price from Binance Market (https://www.binance.com/en/markets) using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current cryptocurrency price, there are several ways.
The easiest way is to use the binance, kucoin or poloniex API.

Example bitcoin price :

```
  let res = await fetch(
    `https://api.poloniex.com/markets/btc_usdt/price`
  );
  let data = await res.json();
  let bitcoin_price = data.price;
```

data :

```
{
  "symbol" : "BTC_USDT",
  "price" : "20083.57",
  "time" : 1664890322436,
  "dailyChange" : "0.0412",
  "ts" : 1664890322442
}
```

Bitcoint price :

```
20083.57
```

You can check more in detail here https://docs.poloniex.com/.